# CUDA out of memory error with a batch size of 1 even after emptying cuda cache

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I'm training a huggingface xlnet-large-cased model with the following specs:
`args = TrainingArguments( f"xlnet-large-finetuned", evaluation_strategy = "epoch", save_strategy = "epoch", learning_rate=2e-5, per_device_train_batch_size=1, per_device_eval_batch_size=1, num_train_epochs=3, gradient_accumulation_steps=16, weight_decay=0.01, load_best_model_at_end=True, metric_for_best_model="accuracy" )`

and by calling this code: `trainer = Trainer( model, args, train_dataset=tokenized_train_dataset, eval_dataset=tokenized_val_dataset, data_collator=data_collator, tokenizer=tokenizer, compute_metrics=compute_metrics )` , `trainer.train()`.

I reduced the batch size to 1, emptied cuda cache and deleted all the variables in gc but I still get this error: `RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 2.00 MiB (GPU 0; 15.78 GiB total capacity; 14.31 GiB already allocated; 2.75 MiB free; 14.78 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch) If reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF`

Is there any way I could resolve this without having to acquire more GPU credits?

Comment: Did you read the documentation as written?

Comment: @Klaus D. Yes I did

Answer (score 0):

There is a method named "Mixed Precision", the idea is to convert parameters from float32 to float16 to speed up the training and reduce memory use, the detail of [mixed precision](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/performance/mixed-precision-training/index.html).

In some repositories, you can see they implement "automatic mixed precision" by [apex package](https://nvidia.github.io/apex/amp.html). However, with the newest version of Pytorch, you can use it easily with [torch.cuda.amp](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/amp.html) by wrapping the computation code in `autocast()` and control the gradient and loss scale by the scaler.